# Is TensorFlow dependent on systemd?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run TensorFlow on my microserver. I'd like to install a non-systemd Linux if possible e.g. Alpine, but I am new to TensorFlow and I am not sure how much it relies on systemd or if it would run without it. Would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow is a regular programming library, it's not a system library and not running as a service, thus it isn't dependent on `systemd`.

I've tested TensorFlow on Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which doesn't come with `systemd` and it's still working.